# AlertDialog OnClose Event Android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have been looking around and I couldn't find anything, so I don't know if its possible, but is there a way to do something on close for alertdialogs?

In my situation, I have the background UI paused while the dialog is up as its a pause screen. If you click the buttons in the dialog it will run the onClick stuff, so I have it unpausing there, but if they click off of the dialog it closes the dialog but doesn't run onClick. Is there anyway to get something to run when they click off to the side? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to not use a AlertDialog.Builder and instead create a PopupWindow sub class.

A good example may be found here on line 37 : 
https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction/blob/master/src/net/londatiga/android/PopupWindows.java

Answer (score 16):

You can set an `onDismissListener()` to listen whenever the dialog goes away. [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnDismissListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener%29).

Comment: Yes, but for `AlertDialog.Builder` that's only introduced in API 17. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setOnDismissListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `onDismissListener()` but it was introduced in higher APIs so will not be compatible with older ones. You can use `onCancel()` instead.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("My Titile");
    alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            //your logic
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false) to force the user to click on the cancel button.
You could also (if you're using a DialogFragment) override the onDetach() method.
And finally you could set a dismiss listener.